# LVM Snapshot mount read-only or not?

Tags: backup, lvm, readonly, snapshot

In [this page](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html) of Linux LVM Howto it's said that "LVM2 creates read/write snapshots by default". In [this other page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/snapshot_volumes.html) of Red Hat docs it's said that "Because the snapshot is read/write, you can test applications against production data by taking a snapshot and running tests against the snapshot, leaving the real data untouched.".

Other sources on internet say that the mount should be read only to preserve original data.

My use case is pretty typical, I want to take a snapshot of my laptop home partition, mount and backup it somewhere else (usb drive). I just wonder, should I mount the snapshot read-only or read-write?

Comment: If you are just backing up the home partition on a laptop that is single user and not running a databases, then there may not be a benefit to taking a snapshot since there is nothing to keep in a consistent state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not plan to change the data just mount it read-only. (This sounds fine for taking a backup.)

If you do plan to change the data, e.g. for running a test against it, then a read-write snapshot is what you want.

Pretty straightforward. :)